# Compile AS project via command line

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flex4

I downloaded Flex SDK 4 and also an .as project with many classes. In order to learn I want to build them and execute. How do I do it ?

I tried with FlashDevelop, but it's not working and when works compile only one single class.

### I READ IT BUT I'M GETTING ERROR. CAN SOMEONE ELSE EXPLAIN IT TO ME IN A NUTSHELL ? THANKS !

THANKS GOD, I ALREADY FIGURED OUT HOW TO DO IT. I HAD TO SET UP THE ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES.

Comment: typing in all caps does not make us answer your question better, take two minutes to explain the problem instead. that way we *can* help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read any of the documentation on using the flex Command line compiler?

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ffd.html

I suggest reading through the docs, and then coming back here with your specific problem.